# How to make smtp setting when send email with SwiftMailer (ssl is already enabled)

Tags: php, gmail, swiftmailer

I want to send email with swiftMailer via php with my gmail. The ssl is already set but it still doesn't work.

Here is my smtp settings in the php:

```
$transport = 
    Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com',465,"ssl")
    ->setUsername('mygmail@gmail.com')
    ->setPassword('mygmailpassword');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
    $message ->setSubject('Welcome to ++');
    $message ->setFrom(array('myemail@gmail.com' => 'websitename'));
    $message ->setTo(array($info['email'] => $info['username']));
```

Here are the settings in the php.ini

```
Edit php.ini and uncomment extension_dir=ext.
Also uncomment extension=php_openssl.dll.
```

Here are the warnings:

Warning: fsockopen(): in C:...\StreamBuffer.php on line 243
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message in C:...\StreamBuffer.php on line 245
Swift_TransportException: in C:...\StreamBuffer.php on line 245

Here is the code between line 243 and 249:

```
if (!$this->_stream = fsockopen($host, $this->_params['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout))
    {
      throw new Swift_TransportException(
        'Connection could not be established with host ' . $this->_params['host'] .
        ' [' . $errstr . ' #' . $errno . ']'
        );
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: [**Be specific**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer. So, what have you tried? **Show some code!**

Comment: You're welcome :-) Can you show the code on line 245? The error states that the problem is there somewhere... Please provide some code before and after line 245 to get a broader view into the source. _Thank you._

Comment: I have posted the code in the question.

Comment: fsockopen is failing, check all the parsed parameters are correct.

Comment: I have checked the parameters, like the setUsername, setPassword, 'smtp.gmail.com',465,"ssl",they seem to be all right... confusing..

Comment: @ShanLuo I think you use port 587. Try changing it to 465.

Comment: It's 465 actually... I have added the $transport definition to the post.

Comment: For now it works! I just restart my computer... I think some settings were wrong. Thanks Markus